# How can i get a specific data from Firbase database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

**Flutter Dart**

in Firestore i can get a specific field value from a specific document where the field is belongs to it like so

```
 final DocumentSnapshot doc = await  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.documentUid).get();

      String name =  doc.get("name");
```

Is this also possible in Firebase data base real time?

i tried this but there no choice like `doc.get("name");`

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(currentUser.uid).then((snapshot) {
      String jj = snapshot.value;
    });
```

ok lets say i set data like so

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("123").set({
      "test1":"test"
    });
```

then i get this into database

```
 testapp-54-default-rtdb
    123 
    test1": test
```

how can i get `test field` which is belongs to the `123` only

thanks so mush for reading my question

[image]

Comment: It would help if you show a screenshot of the data you're working with.  It's not clear what you're trying to read or what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: DONE .... please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a specific data of a path

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(currentUser.uid).child("ok")
  .once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       String jj = snapshot.value;
   });
```

This returns "okkk" in your case.

Or

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(currentUser.uid)
   .once().then(( DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       String jj = snapshot.value["ok"];
    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot , thats what i was looking for , can you please tell me what the sense of putting .once() and is possible to know what is the id is ['ok'] belongs

Comment: .once() will just get the data once and stop listening to that path. To know the parent key of a unique value you can use query. Post a new question for that.

Comment: if you provide me with example i will be so thankful to you , thanks